# Como complementar essa consulta sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Estou com as seguintes tabelas abaixo, aonde esquemas(colunas) estão descritos entre parênteses e a chave primária aparece em negrito:

aluno(**codaluno**, nomealuno, dt_ingresso, codcurso)
curso(**codcurso**, nomecurso)
matrícula(**codaluno**, **codturma**, media, resultado)
turma(**codturma**, periodoletivo, sala, codprof, coddisc)
disciplina(**coddisc**, título, créditos)
professor(**codprof**, nomeprofessor, titulação)

Desejo realizar a seguinte consulta sql:

> Qual o nome, a nota média (considerando as médias todas as disciplinas em que se matriculou) e o total de créditos obtido por cada aluno? Lembre-se que um aluno somente obtém créditos numa disciplina se for aprovado nesta disciplina.

Eu já consegui a seguinte expressão sql:

```
SELECT nomealuno, sum(media)/count(codaluno) FROM aluno 
NATURAL JOIN matricula GROUP BY aluno.codaluno;
```

Aonde são listados os nomes dos alunos e as suas respectivas media, mas ainda falta obter o total de créditos e ainda realizar a condição "somente obtém créditos numa disciplina se for aprovado nesta disciplina". Como complementar minha consulta sql para obter os requisitos restantes acima?

Relacionamento como pedido nos comentários:

[image: Relacionamento]

> Obs: Essas setas indicam as chaves estrangeiras que foram importadas.

Comment: @gmsantos sim matrícula(codaluno, codturma, media, resultado) está na coluna resultado... que é o resultado da matrícula se o aluno foi aprovado ou não.

Comment: Qual é o tipo de dado nessa coluna de resultado? Ela diz se o aluno foi aprovado na disciplina, é isso? É um booleano? 0/1?

Comment: @bfavaretto sim

Comment: Tenta :


`SELECT aluno.nomealuno, sum(matricula.media)/count(aluno.codaluno), sum(disciplina.creditos) FROM aluno, matricula, disciplina, turma WHERE aluno.codaluno = matricula.codaluno AND matricula.codturma = turma.codturma AND turma.coddisc = disciplina.coddisc GROUP BY aluno.codaluno;`


Não coloco ainda como resposta porque ainda não testei.

Comment: E eu sugiro: `SELECT a.nomealuno, AVG(m.media), SUM(IF(m.resultado=1, d.creditos, 0)) FROM aluno a 
LEFT JOIN matricula m ON a.codaluno = m.codaluno 
LEFT JOIN turma t ON m.codturma = t.codturma 
LEFT JOIN disciplina d ON t.coddisc = d.coddisc 
GROUP BY a.codaluno` não tenho banco para testar rs

Comment: @PedroRangel Pode testar com mais dados fake editando o SQL Fiddle que eu criei: **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8755/5**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solução

```
SELECT a.nomealuno, AVG(m.media), SUM(IF(m.resultado=1, d.creditos, 0)) 
FROM aluno a LEFT JOIN matricula m ON a.codaluno = m.codaluno 
LEFT JOIN turma t ON m.codturma = t.codturma 
LEFT JOIN disciplina d ON t.coddisc = d.coddisc 
GROUP BY a.codaluno
```

### Referências

- [GROUP BY functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)
- [IF Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html)

Comment: so a titulo de curiosidade o que esse on faz?

Comment: é condição de para união dos dados. O mesmo pode ser representado nos WHERE. Creio que a mesma query poderia ser representada assim: `SELECT a.nomealuno, AVG(m.media), SUM(IF(m.resultado=1, d.creditos, 0)) 
FROM aluno a, matricula m, turma t, disciplina d 
WHERE a.codaluno = m.codaluno AND m.codturma = t.codturma AND t.coddisc = d.coddisc 
GROUP BY a.codaluno`

Comment: vlw esse select aew funciona tmb mas nao mostra todos os alunos que nao possuem matricula^^ agradeço mais uma vez.

Comment: detalhe adicional: quando você faz left join, você está dizendo que "quem manda" na consulta é a tabela do lado esquerdo (left), com isso, caso não tenho dados do lado direito, ele devolve null. Se quiser inverter a prioridade, você faz um right join. Se quiser fazer com que os dados só venham se existir dados em todas as tabelas você faz apenas JOIN (removendo o left e o right).

Comment: é, eu esqueci um detalhe, não mostra porque quando você faz join pelo where, você está forçando um JOIN (sem left ou right join). rs

Comment: As *keywords* `INNER` e `OUTER` são dispensáveis?

Comment: @Patrick veja este link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join